# Stress-energy tensor and inertia mass?

Tags: general-relativity

In GR, $T^{\mu\nu}$ is the source of gravitation. How do different component of stress-energy tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$ contribute to its inertia mass? Namely, if a force acts on a matter with $T^{\mu\nu}$, how is the four-acceleration related to the force?

More intuitively, if two boxes of matter with the same rest mass energy but different pressure, do they weigh differently on a balance on Earth?

Comment: The stress-energy tensor describes spacetime itself, not an object in spacetime. If you're looking for how an object reacts to force, start with that object's four-momentum.

Comment: @probably_someone $T_{\mu \nu}$ describes the source of curvature. The spacetime (curvature) is described by $g_{\mu \nu}$

Comment: @Avantgarde Thanks for correcting the somewhat-imprecise terminology. The fact remains that the $T_{\mu\nu}$ is not a property of an individual object, but rather is a property of a particular point in spacetime.

Comment: @probably_someone I'm not sure I understood you correctly, but are you saying that $T_{\mu \nu}$ can be specified without invoking any 'matter'?

Comment: @Avantgarde That is not what I'm saying. Specifying $T_{\mu\nu}$ requires you to know the energy density, and this requires knowing how matter is distributed. It does not refer to a _particular_ object, though. You can't talk about "a baseball with stress-energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$;" rather, you would talk about "the stress-energy tensor in _the region of spacetime currently containing this baseball_". The stress-energy tensor is not a property assignable to an object; rather, it is a property of a point in spacetime.

Comment: @Avantgarde After thinking about this a bit longer, I'm not sure that I'm correct about this. For example, the electric field is in a similar situation, not necessarily ascribable to a particular object, yet we often refer to the electric field _of_ an object as the field emitted _by_ that object. I suppose this logic could work in general relativity - the stress-energy tensor of an object is the stress-energy tensor of a universe containing only that object. I haven't seen that usage before, but that doesn't mean it's not potentially common.

Comment: @probably_someone Once you decide that $T_{\mu \nu}(x)$ ($J^\mu(x)$) is decided by matter (charge) distribution, how you interpret where it 'lives' becomes a matter of semantics, so it doesn't really matter as long as you're concerned with solving equations with it.

Comment: I would like to know how a complicated matter/not just point particle with mass m react under force, i.e. its equation of motion, not how it contributes to the gravity via Einstein field equation.